# How do I connect ASP.NET Core services using MassTransit with Application Insights?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, masstransit

I have several ASP.NET Core microservices.  Most of them communicate with each other via MassTransit on top of RabbitMQ.  I don't see anything show up in AppInsights when messages are published from one service to another.  I would think I would see something in the application map and transaction search views.

I've found several bits of documentation, including here (https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/monitoring/applications-insights.html) of course.  But, this page mainly documents a console app with direct involvement of a **TelemetryClient**.  I have a more traditional DI-based startup file:

```
            services.AddCloudRoleNameInitializer("AgencyService");
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

            var rabbitSettings = services.GetTransportSettings(Configuration);
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host(rabbitSettings.Host, rabbitSettings.Name, h =>
                    {
                        h.Username(rabbitSettings.Username);
                        h.Password(rabbitSettings.Password);
                    });
                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);

                });
            });
```

I've tried adding something like this:

```
            services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>((telemetryModule, options) =>
                telemetryModule.IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities.Add("MassTransit"));
```

But, that does not seem to work.

So, what's the best way to configure MT work with App Insights with this style approach?

Answer (score 1):

MassTransit uses Open Telemetry, so you'd need to use the Azure Monitor exporter for it. [This sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ApplicationInsights/blob/master/ASP.NET.API/Startup.cs#L34) should get you started, it shows how to configure MassTransit to use Application Insights.

The key configuration section is:

```cs
services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing(builder =>
{
    builder.SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
            .AddService("AgencyService")
            .AddTelemetrySdk()
            .AddEnvironmentVariableDetector())
        .AddSource("MassTransit")
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddAzureMonitorTraceExporter(o =>
        {
            o.ConnectionString = Configuration["ApplicationInsightsConnectionString"];
        });
});
```